# Create a unique file and filename based on every unique value in a column in a DataTable with .net

Tags: .net

I am trying to create a file with a file name based on the value in a column in a DataTable, for example:

```
Dim UserID As String = String.Empty  
UserID = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(0)  
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\" + UserID + "_File.txt")
```

but I am having trouble with the logic that would create a new file when the UserID changes in the dataset, basically I want a unique file for every UserID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim distdt As DataTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "UserID")

    For Each row In distdt.Rows

        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\" + row.item(0).ToString + "_file.txt")

            For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                If row.item(0).ToString = dr.item(0).ToString Then
                    sw.WriteLine(dr.Item(1))
                End If
            Next

        End Using

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my examples in C#. If you want to see them in VB, consider using [Telerik's Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).

The data in the DataTable wasn't provided so I wrote a quick console app that will create the DataTable and populate it as well as create the files but only if a file has not already been created for a given UserId. Note this is limited to a single execution context, otherwise you need to access the file system and check for existing files with specific names.

I have provided two versions of the code for your reference, one without using Linq and one with.

I know in your question you used a new StreamWriter and may have content to write to the file.  This can be done by replacing the File.Create line or using the returned FileStream from File.Create().  You can modify my code to use the returned FileStream by removing the Dispose() call. Just be sure to manually call Dispose() yourself or, better yet, wrap it in a using.

Without using Linq

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace UniqueFileNames
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string UserIdColumnName = "UserId";
        private const string FilePath = "C:\\Example\\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create table and add column
            var sampleDataTable = new DataTable();
            sampleDataTable.Clear();
            sampleDataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
            sampleDataTable.Columns.Add(UserIdColumnName);

            // Add some rows for sample data
            AddData(sampleDataTable, 1);

            // add the data again to prove we don't recreate a file for same userid (later)
            AddData(sampleDataTable, 2);

            // Create a directory to hold our files. Doing so at the root can cause permission issues
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath);

            // This will store what UserIds have already had files created for them
            var userIdsWhereFileHasAlreadyBeenCreated = new HashSet<string>();            

            // Loop through each row in our data table, generate the file name, display a mesage, and create the file
            foreach (DataRow row in sampleDataTable.Rows) // another, cleaner option would be to select distinct UserIds from the Rows collection
            {
                var currentUserid = row[UserIdColumnName].ToString();
                var fileName = string.Format("{0}_File.txt", row[UserIdColumnName]);

                // Check to see if this userId has already had a file created for this execution
                if (!userIdsWhereFileHasAlreadyBeenCreated.Contains(currentUserid))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating a file named {0} at location {1}", fileName, FilePath));
                    File.Create(string.Format("{0}{1}", FilePath, fileName)).Dispose();

                    // Add the UserId so that we do not try to create a file for this UserId again
                    userIdsWhereFileHasAlreadyBeenCreated.Add(currentUserid);
                }
                else // this UserId already had a file created for it during this execution
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("A file named {0} at location {1} already exists", fileName, FilePath));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void AddData(DataTable sampleDataTable, int iteration)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var row = sampleDataTable.NewRow();
                row[UserIdColumnName] = string.Format("user{0}", i);

                // generate incremented Ids based on iteration to show duplicate values between rows for UserId
                row["Id"] = i + (10 * iteration); 
                sampleDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With using Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace UniqueFileNames
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string UserIdColumnName = "UserId";
        private const string FilePath = "C:\\Example\\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create table and add column
            var sampleDataTable = new DataTable();
            sampleDataTable.Clear();
            sampleDataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
            sampleDataTable.Columns.Add(UserIdColumnName);

            // Add some rows for sample data
            AddData(sampleDataTable, 1);

            // add the data again to prove we don't recreate a file for same userid (later)
            AddData(sampleDataTable, 2);

            // Create a directory to hold our files. Doing so at the root can cause permission issues
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath);

            // We take the rows and select each row's UserId column and then to a Distinct() on that result. 
            // This gives us an IEnumerable<string> of distinct UserIds
            // Loop through each row in our data table, generate the file name, display a mesage, and create the file
            foreach (var currentUserId in sampleDataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => r[UserIdColumnName].ToString()).Distinct())
            {
                var fileName = string.Format("{0}_File.txt", currentUserId);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating a file named {0} at location {1}", fileName, FilePath));
                File.Create(string.Format("{0}{1}", FilePath, fileName)).Dispose();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void AddData(DataTable sampleDataTable, int iteration)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var row = sampleDataTable.NewRow();
                row[UserIdColumnName] = string.Format("user{0}", i);

                // generate incremented Ids based on iteration to show duplicate values between rows for UserId
                row["Id"] = i + (10 * iteration);
                sampleDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @sqllayman did this help you? Do you need any other information or anything?

Comment: I used 2 different datatables, 1 getting the unique list of IDs (dt1) then a For Each dt1 ...  Using Writer ... For Each  dt2  If dt1.ID=dt2.ID then write  that worked fairly well...

Comment: Appreciate you following up! Sorry if my answer was not what you were looking for.